# How do I create a regex for 2 different patterns that outputs in 1 group, in Google sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have this google sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u0gIvdv_W-1ANLD-7n1kZHv1b2RHMr_IJyALS7IxScg/edit?usp=sharing

I was able to successfully create a regex to extract a number percentage from data within parentheses:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "([0-9]+)%")
```

and was able to do the same to a certain extend, to output the topic within parentheses.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "\((\D+)\s\d+%\)|\((\D+)\s\d+\)")
```

The problem is that the regex output matched copy to 2 different groups and google sheets decided to output the match for group 2, to the next column (As you can see on line 28)

How can I have google sheets use the same cell, no matter what the group is?

Comment: Concatenate the results of the different regex calls?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the formula:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\((.*)")," ?\d{1,2}%\)|\)","")
```

- First step is: `REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\((.*)")` will produce the result in parentheses including `)`.
- The second part `REGEXREPLACE(text," ?\d{1,2}%\)|\)","")` will remove digits with `%` or `)`